# Does this simple 2D dynamical system have a conserved quantity?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Consider the following two-dimensional dynamical system,

$$\dot{x} = y -y^3$$
$$\dot{y}= -x-y^2$$

where as usual the dot represents a time derivative. (This system is found on page 165 of Strogatz book 'Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos'.)

**I am trying to find a conserved quantity for this system**, apparently it does exist and there is a simple way to find it. Strogatz shows that the system is reversible with a nonlinear center at the origin. The phase portrait looks like:

[image]

Does this system have a conserved quantity? Something like $x^2+y^2 = \text{constant}$, for example (this does not work though...). If so how would I go about finding it?

I have tried playing around with the system but have not been able to find one, however the phase portrait leads me to believe that something should be conserved.

Comment: Just a follow-up comment and sort of an advice. In principle reversibility gives you here everything you need for a qualitative analysis of system - no need for seeking first integral really. Note that not all reversible systems are conservative - any system that has symmetric source or sink is an example.

Comment: I dont think reverisable implies conservative. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-84570-3_27.  the author seems to state this in the 3rd paragraph, assuming his conservative definition is the same, which he doesnt state i dont think.

Comment: my bad, totally misread Evgeny's comment... Why do you think there is a simple way to find it? where does Strogatz say that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Follow up answer to @lhf's post*

---

The equation

$$(y-y^3) \, \partial_x H - (x+y^2) \, \partial_y H = 0, $$ as proposed by @lhf, is a linear first-order PDE for $H$. The method of characteristics then states that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y-y^3} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{-x-y^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}H}{0}, $$

where the last fraction indicates that $H = c_1$ is a constant along the characteristic curve defined by the first equals sign:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\frac{x+y^2}{y(1-y^2)}$$

which defines $y$ as a function of $x$. The solution to this (homogeneous?) equation is given by Mathematica as:

$$ \small{
\left(\sqrt{3}+3\right) \log \left[\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) y^2-2 x-\sqrt{3}-1\right]
-\left(\sqrt{3}-3\right) \log \left[\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right) y^2+2 x-\sqrt{3}+1\right]=c_2 
}
$$ 
where I have absorbed a factor into the constant of integration. Put now $c_1$ as a function of $c_2$ to have $H = f(c_2)$, where $ f $ is an arbitrary function of its argument. Take for instance $f(\square) = \square$ as the identity function and you will thus find:

$$ \small{
H = 
\left(\sqrt{3}+3\right) \log \left[\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) y^2-2 x-\sqrt{3}-1\right]
-\left(\sqrt{3}-3\right) \log \left[\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right) y^2+2 x-\sqrt{3}+1\right]
}$$

which, if I didn't make any mistake on the transcription, satisfies the original PDE.

Hope you find this useful!

---

Check with Mathematica:
[image]

Comment: I just checked on wolfram and indeed it seems to satisfy the original equation! Do you mind double checking in mathematica?

Comment: Please see my edit @Dman

Comment: great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dmoreno how exactly did you use mathematica to derive the parametric equation? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi @Alex, what do you mean by 'the parametric equation'?

Comment: @Dmoreno, What I mean is, how did you solve $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\frac{x+y^2}{y(1-y^2)}$$ analytically using Mathematica?

Comment: Hi @Alex, please use the following command: DSolve[y'[x] == - (x + y[x]^2)/(y[x] (1 - y[x]^2)), y[x], x]

Answer (score 2):

A conserved quantity $H(x,y)$ must be such that $H(x,y)$ is constant on the integral curves. This happens iff $H_x \dot x + H_y \dot y =0$. So you want to solve
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}( y -y^3) + \frac{\partial H}{\partial y}( -x-y^2) = 0
$$
This suggests that you may try a polynomial for $H$, perhaps with an integrating factor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How does one go about solving this PDE?

Comment: @Dman, I don't know the solution. I tried the obvious $\dot x= -H_y, \dot y = H_x$, but it didn't work out.

Comment: @Dman, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252788/which-of-the-following-is-gradient-hamiltonian-conservative-system.

Comment: Considering that close to the origin the system looks like a harmonic oscillator, thought it was worth trying $H = x^2 + y^2 + \Phi(x,y)$, where $\Phi $ is a polynomial going quickly to zero  towards the origin, but no luck

Comment: @lhf what is meant by 'integrating factor'?

Comment: @Dman, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor

Comment: Note that $$\small{H = \left(\sqrt{3}+3\right) \log \left(-2 x+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) y^2-\sqrt{3}-1\right)-\left(\sqrt{3}-3\right) \log \left(2 x+\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right) y^2-\sqrt{3}+1\right)}$$ is a solution of the PDE proposed by @lhf (I used the method of characteristics and Mathematica)