# Solve parametric differential equation using Mathematica

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, parametric, mathematica

Using the method of characteristics on a PDE system, I have gotten a parametric differential equation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y - xy}{1 + xy - x}.
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are both functions of a third variable $t$. How could I use Mathematica to solve for the solution curve that $(x(t), y(t))$ follows? There is a similar approach done here: [Does this simple 2D dynamical system have a conserved quantity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358468/does-this-simple-2d-dynamical-system-have-a-conserved-quantity).

EDIT: The system where this came from is
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= x - xy \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= 1 + xy - y
\end{align*}

EDIT2: Just to be clear, I know how to draw solution curves with Mathematica. What I am wondering if there is a way to solve the equation analytically and get a closed form curve as the solution.

Comment: I don't see how this equation can tell us anything about $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. It only constrains the form of $y(x)$.

Comment: I think that's kind of the point - given this equation, you should be able to write an equation of the form f(x, y) = 0 where f is some function.

Comment: What is the PDE ? Is there a boundary condition ?

Comment: @JJacquelin I don't think that's super relevant here. I just want to know if there is a way to solve the given equation using mathematica. We should get some kind of curve of the form f(x, y) = 0 for some function f in terms of x and y, regardless if there is a boundary condition.

Comment: @JJacquelin just added the system where this came from.

Comment: @Alex. If so, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y - xy}{1 + xy - x}$ instead of $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1+xy-y}{x-xy}.$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
ai = -0.4; tm = 10;
EQ = {X'[t] == X[t] (1 - Y[t]), Y'[t] == 1 + Y[t] (X[t] - 1), 
   X[0] == ai, Y[0] == 2.75};
NDSolve[EQ, {X, Y}, {t, 0, tm}];
{x[u_], y[u_]} = {X[u], Y[u]} /. First[%];
p1 = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tm}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

The above is *Mathematica* coding (that can be subtantially improved) for three boundary conditions (blue,red,magenta) $ { (x_i,y_i)= (-0.4,2.75),(-.2,4), (4.4,3.75) } $

[Mathematica Link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176332/boundary-condition-change-in-coupled-odes/176334#176334)

Answer (score 2):

Attached some MATHEMATICA code to help in this question

`grf0 = StreamPlot[{x - x y, 1 - x y - y}, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}];
sols = Solve[{x - x y == 0, 1 - x y - y == 0}, {x, y}];
pts = {x, y} /. sols;
grpts = Table[Graphics[{Red, Disk[pts[[i]], 0.2]}], {i, 1, Length[pts]}];
tmax = 5;
sols = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] - x[t] y[t], y'[t] == 1 - x[t] y[t] - y[t], x[0] == -7, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sols], {t, 0, tmax},PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[grf0, grpts, gr2]`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cesareo, but do you know if there is a way to solve the system analytically for the closed form of the curve using Mathematica? That's what I was asking for in the OP.

Comment: @Alex It seems that  MATHEMATICA cannot solve this differential system in closed form.